# Difference between android:orientation="vertical" vs android:orientation="horizontal"

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering what the difference are between these two? benefits of one over the other? etc...

Comment: +1 to counter downvote; for beginners, it can be confusing when coupled with phone orientation which is a different matter. I think Haphazard and Tim's answers explain best

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"horizontal" allows your elements within the Layout to be placed beside each other where as "vertical" will stack them.  There aren't really benefits to either - use the one that best fits your design.

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) says: "Should the layout be a column or a row? Use "horizontal" for a row, "vertical" for a column."

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know they are only relevant for the LinearLayout. And it determines wither your views get stacked vertically like this:

```
View1

View2

View3

View4

etc...
```

or horizontally like this:

```
View1 View2 View3 View4 etc...
```

Comment: they're also relevant for layout containers which extend from LinearLayout, like TableView, TableRow etc

Answer (score 7):

horizontal:

```
# # # # # # # # # # #
```

vertical:

```
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
```

Comment: While this answer deals with the definition of horizontal and vertical it doesn't make the xml property less ambiguous (granted, for people that haven't read the LinearLayout docs), specifically that many beginners think this property is to do with phone orientation, rather than elements within a view container.