# Explain this android:orientation:"vertical"

Tags: android, android-layout

What is android here?
what is Orientation here?
What is Vertical ?

I would be pleased to know if they are classes or packages or methods..?
I am confused?
Can some one explain hierarchy of it?

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you have seen this inside the `<LinearLayout>`.

It means that whatever view you take inside the LinearLayout will be shown in screen by vertical (like Stake of views).

Every attributes started with **android** followed by **:** so here **orientation is an attribute** and **vertical is the value to be assigned this attribute**.

### Update:

(Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116910/difference-between-androidorientation-vertical-vs-androidorientation-horizo/6116970#6116970).)

For `android:orientation="vertical"`, your views get stacked vertically like this:

```
View1

View2

View3

View4

etc...
```

And For `android:orientation="horizontal"`, your views gets placed horizontally like this:

```
View1 View2 View3 View4 etc...
```

Comment: I am very thankful for the information. I am aware about its functionalities but my questions is when a xml tagis given how does it render in code... Are there any methods related to these xml attributes. My concern is about internal working

Comment: @SunilGandham Why haven't you mentioned this in question? You should provide enough detail while asking question

Answer (score 0):

This is the XML tag for the Layout properties of any Layout Widget for Android UI.
android:orientation is the XML tag and "vertical" is value for the same. so when it will be loaded in UI framework, child of the layout will be arranged in vertical form.

Answer (score 0):

These are Input parameters for XML tags . Although Java is an object oriented language ,but it does not means that you will consider every element of android as Classes . XML Layout structure is view forming technique which use native kit internally .so these @android:something are just identifier to tell the native kit what to do . nothing else .

Comment: I am very thankful for the information. I am aware about its functionalities but my questions is when a xml tagis given how does it render in code... Are there any methods related to these xml attributes. My concern is about internal working

Answer (score 0):

This is the code written in android.widget.LinearLayout.java

```
 @Override
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
                if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
                    layoutVertical();
                } else {
                    layoutHorizontal();
                }
 }
```

You can view the **[SOURCE CODE HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/LinearLayout.java.htm)**, Based on the orientation and gravity attribute how the android sets Child Views into Parent.