# Buttons with background image not next to each other?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I also tried fill_parent,match_parent instead of wrap_content. I want two buttons with background image in one row. I tried using weightSum="2" and each button having layout_weigh="1". But it is not working . Please someone suggest where i am going wrong. My XML file is below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="2">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button5"
         style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@drawable/theatre"
         android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
         android:paddingBottom="18dp"
         android:text="THEATRE"
         android:textColor="@color/green" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/butt3"
         style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@drawable/hospital_icon"
         android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
         android:paddingBottom="18dp"
         android:text="HOSPITAL"
         android:textColor="@color/green" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:background="@drawable/pubs"
         android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
         android:paddingBottom="18dp"
         android:text="PUBS"
         android:textColor="@color/green" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/hotel"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="HOTELS"
        android:textColor="@color/green" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mall"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:text="MALLS"
        android:textColor="@color/green" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/monum"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        android:text="MONUMENTS"
        android:textColor="@color/green" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="EXPENSE CALCULATOR"
        android:textColor="@color/green" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: orientation = "horizontal"

See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116910/difference-between-androidorientation-vertical-vs-androidorientation-horizo

Comment: hi Nimit  I think you have to require equal size Button in LinearLayout am i right?

Comment: To place into one row change the orientation from vertical to horizontal in xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="THEATRE"
            android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butt3"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="HOSPITAL"
            android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="PUBS"
            android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="HOTELS"
            android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="MALLS"
            android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="MONUMENTS"
            android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="EXPENSE CALCULATOR"
        android:textColor="@color/cream_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yeah it worked. But the size of the buttons is not same. How to make them of same size?

Comment: Which buttons you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use  orientation as **horizontal** if you want to display next to each other

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Also, when you specify weight for width then you should not use **wrap_content** for **button5** & **button3**

```
        android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Also there are some other buttons as well in your layout, use different layout for them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below line copy and paste with you xml  - If you to require one row with equal size button width.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
             android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:background="@drawable/theatre"
             android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
             android:paddingBottom="18dp"
             android:text="THEATRE"
             android:textColor="@color/green" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/butt3"
             style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:background="@drawable/hospital_icon"
             android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
             android:paddingBottom="18dp"
             android:text="HOSPITAL"
             android:textColor="@color/green" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:weight="1"
             style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"

             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
             android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:background="@drawable/pubs"
             android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
             android:paddingBottom="18dp"
             android:text="PUBS"
             android:textColor="@color/green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:weight="1"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hotel"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="HOTELS"
            android:textColor="@color/green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/mall"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="MALLS"
            android:textColor="@color/green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/monum"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="MONUMENTS"
            android:textColor="@color/green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="EXPENSE CALCULATOR"
            android:textColor="@color/green" />
    </LinearLayout>
```